# Find local max/min and saddle points of $f(x,y) = e^x\cos(y)$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I want to find the local max/min and saddle points of $f(x,y) = e^x\cos(y)$.

I started off by finding the following:

\begin{align}
f_x &= e^x\cos(y) \\
f_{xx} &= e^x\cos(y) \\
f_y &= -e^x\sin(y) \\
f_{yy} &= -e^x\cos(y) \\
f_{xy} &= -e^x\sin(y)
\end{align}

I know I will need the following:

\begin{align}
f_x &= 0 \\
f_y &= 0
\end{align}

Now, $\cos(y) = 0$ whenever $y = \frac{\pi}{2}$. Thus, $\frac{\pi}{2}$ would make $f_x = 0$.

Am I proceeding in the right direction?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a plot of $f(x,y)$ (maybe it's useful?):

[image]

**Edit**

Since there exists no $x$ that satisfies both $f_x=0$ and $f_y=0$, there are no critical points nor saddle points.

Comment: Okay. I also know that $\sin(y) = 0$ when $y = 0 + 2\pi n$, which tells me when $f_y = 0$. I'm a bit lost where to go from here.

Comment: Well, I think my problem is that I have the $y$-coordinates of two different points, right? Namely, $(x_1, \frac{\pi}{2} + 2\pi n)$ and $(x_2, 0 + 2\pi n)$. I need to find what $x_1$ and $x_2$ are before I proceed to the second derivative test?